# How do I install freeTTS in 12.04?

Tags: java, libraries, speech-recognition

I am working on speech recognition in java; for which I require a third party library. As I need to import classes like javax.speech.Recognition in my code.

I downloaded the source code from this link :- [freeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#download_and_install)

But wasn't able to make any progress :(,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to install from source because FreeTTS *is available in the repositories.*

- Click below to install FreeTTS via the Software Centre:

  [image: Install via the software center]
- Or, open a terminal, and run `sudo apt-get install freetts`